# R extremely slow processing loop

Tags: r

So I am gathering data from a relatively decent sized excel file (~200k rows, 35 columns). The data is broken up with a section name, cycle count, and then the next row is the data, and at the end of the data section is a blank line. So here is my function that gets the data, file for the parameter is all the files in the directory ending in .csv that have to be parsed and name is the name of the section of data that you want to get. The function works, but it runs at a snail pace, and by that I mean to process 10k lines about 4 minutes.

```
getData1 <- function(file,name) {
  for(i in 1:length(file)) {
    dat <- c()
    lines <- readLines(file[i])
    indx <- grep(name,  lines) #row number for anything with search term in it

    counter <- 3
    dat <- c(read.table(text=lines[(indx+2)],
                      sep=",", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE))

    while(dat[counter-2] != "\t") {
         dat <- c(dat,read.table(text=lines[(indx+counter)],  #read only one line per loop
                             sep=",", header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, check.names=FALSE))

         counter <- counter + 1
    }
    return(dat)
  }
}
```

Comment: Read circle 2 of http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf (Growing objects)

Comment: To be a bit more explicit in that, the operation `dat <- c(dat, something.else)` being called repeatedly in a loop is very slow in R.

Comment: Thanks will give it a read

Comment: Maybe you could provide a little bit of your data (a few columns, and a few short records, or a bigger chunk in some on-line location) so that it's easier to imagine what you're trying to do.

Comment: I second Martin Morgan, but would approach the problem by indexing the beginning like you have, and also the ending line. Then you could subtract the two and use the nrows argument to read in only the rows you need. Doing something like grep('\t',lines) will give you all possible end lines. Filter by those greater than the start, and take the min (+/- whatever additional math you have in there).

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying Robertson that probably would be alot faster.